# Unterschied: "Übermut" vs "Mutwille"?

Tags: meaning, standard-german, difference

hab im Duden angeschaut, die Unterschiede in den Bedeutungen sind so fein, dass man sehr schwierig die Wörter richtig merkt. Bitte die Profis um Tipps damit man besser die Unterschiede in Benutzung und Bedeutung merkt....

Comment: keine Rechtsberatung hier. Davon ab könnte man *Mutwille* mit *Meuterei*, Sowie *Übermut* mit *lebensmüde* vergleichen (doch beides zweifelhaft). Irgendwas war da noch, weshalb *Mut* nicht ohne weiteres zu En. *mood* gestellt werden sollte wie sonst üblich--aber ich komm grad nicht drauf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Abgrenzung ist sicher nicht völlig eindeutig, aber der Duden trifft eine durchaus sichtbare Unterscheidung:

**Übermut**

> 1. ausgelassene Fröhlichkeit, die sich in leichtsinnigem, mutwilligem Verhalten ausdrückt
> 2. Selbstüberschätzung zum Nachteil anderer

**Mutwille**

> absichtliche, bewusste, vorsätzliche Boshaftigkeit, Leichtfertigkeit

Vgl. auch

**übermütig**

> 1. voller Übermut; von Übermut zeugend

> Beispiele

```
    ein übermütiger Streich
    übermütig herumtollen
    werdet nicht übermütig, Kinder!
```

> 2. stolz, überheblich

> Synonyme : aufgezogen, ausgelassen, fröhlich, lustig

**mutwillig**

> aus Mutwillen [geschehend, herbeigeführt]

> Beispiele

```
    mutwillige Beschädigung
    etwas mutwillig beschädigen
```

> Synonyme : absichtlich, absichtsvoll, beabsichtigt, bewusst

*Übermütig sein* bedeutet also, im Überschwang der Gefühle etwas Unüberlegtes bzw. Leichtsinniges zu tun und ggf. damit auch sich selbst zu schaden. *Mutwillig sein* bedeutet dagegen, absichtlich etwas zu tun, das in der Regel jemand anderem schadet.